# Laptop model identification

Tags: laptop, display

Trying to get OS installed, but neither vga nor hdmi out work.

Obstacles:

1. There are no stickers under it
2. Screens broken
3. No OS to use software ident.

The only thing I know about it is the screen sticker says HP 2000 but I don't know the specific model.

btw I can open up the laptop but would need to know where to look.

Any suggestions?

(This things become a hassle to fix, buying a new ltop seems like the least problematic solution.)

Comment: A laptop and the screen is broken.... sounds like trash to me if it's old...  In either case, get the screen fixed so you can see what it is doing or connect it to an external monitor and watch it boot up, go into the BIOS, etc. You obviously need to be able to see the video output to install the OS regardless...

Comment: How do you know its even running?

Comment: Yeah, but to cut costs I'm trying to find the model number to order the screen specific to the laptop. And I tried to connect it to the monitor I use for my desktop using both the vga and hdmi connections, either way theres no output.

Answer (score -2):

When you switch it on, press F10 (and hold).

This will get you into the boot menu; there you should be able to learn all about the hardware.

Comment: Screen is broken...I am not the person with the problem,...just confused by this answer

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.